# Confusion on convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I got a problem while solving a problem regarding convex functions on an interval $(a,b)$. What I had to show is if $f$ is convex then $f'$ exists except possibly at countably many points and is $\geq0$. I proved that. But according to the definition $f(x)=x^2$ is also convex but the derivative is negative on $(-\infty,0)$. So i am so confused now? Can somebody help me to figure out where did I get wrong here?

Comment: The second derivative is positive, not the first.  If you show us how you did part 1, we can see the problem.

Comment: Given $x,y\in (a,b)$ such that $x\leq y$ and $z\in (a,b)$ such that $z<x$ we have $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z}\leq \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z} \leq \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{x-z}$. So $f(x)\leq f(y)$. Hence $f$ is monotonically increasing. Still can't figure out the mistake.

Comment: The second inequality is only true if $f(y)\geq f(z)$

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot the fact that the numerators can be negative

Comment: Ok then I can show that $f'$ exists except possibly at countably many points and also it is monotonically increasing where it exist. Then does it directly imply that $f''\geq 0$? or should I show first that $f''$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'$ must be monotonic non-decreasing (and not $f$).

---

Definition of convex function is a function in which function of weighted averages is always less than weighted average of functions:

$$ f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\leq\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2) $$

$$\lambda \in [0,1]$$

It can be shown that $f'(x)$ is monotonic non-decreasing.

Let $x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4 \in(a,b):x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$

$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2} \leq \frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}$$

Let 
$$x_2\to x_1^+$$
$$x_3\to x_4^-$$

Then

$$f'(x_1)\leq f'(x_4)$$

And if you ask where does that in inequality come from here is the proof:

$$ f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\leq\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2) $$

Let say $x=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$ then $x_1<x<x_2$

and I can show that

$$\lambda=\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}$$

$$1-\lambda=\frac{x-x-1}{x_2-x_1}$$

$$ f(x)\leq \frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1} f(x_1)+\frac{x-x-1}{x_2-x_1}f(x_2) $$

$$ (x_2-x_1)f(x)\leq (x_2-x) f(x_1)+(x-x-1)f(x_2) $$

$$ (x_2-x+x-x_1)f(x)\leq (x_2-x) f(x_1)+(x-x-1)f(x_2) $$

$$ 0\leq (x_2-x) (f(x_1)-f(x))+(x-x-1)(f(x_2)-f(x)) $$

$$  (x_2-x) (f(x)-f(x_1)) \leq (x-x-1)(f(x_2)-f(x)) $$

$$  \frac{ f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1} \leq \frac{f(x_2)-f(x)}{x_2-x} $$

Conclusion

$$f''(x)\geq 0$$

Comment: How do you directly conclude that $f''\geq 0$ here? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mathi
I proved for any $x_1\leq x_4$ we have $f'(x_1)\leq f'(x_4)$, therefore $f'$ is monotonic non-decreasing and we expect that $(f')'\geq 0$

Comment: But here $f'$ is not continuous. It exists except possibly at countably many points.

Comment: @Mathi How do you say $f(x)=x^2$ is non-continuous? is there any extra condition on the function?

Comment: Oh I am not talking about $f(x)=x^2$. I am considering a general convex function.

Comment: @Mathi Yes, in general cases, it is in case of existence of  $f'$ . For a convex function, $f'$ needs to be monotonic non-decreasing everywhere (unless countable points). $f''\geq0$ must be correct when $f''$ does exist. Convex functions are not being defined with $f'$ or $f''$ anything related to them are in case of their existence.